# Crypto hmac conversion from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I'm trying to convert the following function from Python to Javascript.
Currently concentrating on the generation of the signature.

```
def prepare_url(self, segments, params={}):
        if self.token is not None:
            sig = hmac.new(self.token.key.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha1)
            sig.update(self.method.lower().encode())
            sig.update(self.service.lower().encode())
            

            ts = self.get_timestamp(self.token.server_offset)
            sig.update(ts.encode())
            params["timestamp"] = ts

            sig.update(self.token.identifier.lower().encode())
 
            params["signature-method"] = "auth"
            params["signature-version"] = self.version
            params["signature"] = base64.standard_b64encode(sig.digest())
 
        self.url = "%s/%s/%d/" % (self.base_path, self.service, self.version)
        self.url += "/".join([urllib.parse.quote(s) for s in segments])
        if params:
            self.url += "?%s" % urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
```

In Javascript I'm using the crypto library and have the following code:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

const KEY = '5d016f32-452f-4b9b-8e81-641e14d4d98c';
const METHOD = 'get';
const SERVICE = 'data';
const date = (new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 19);

const encoded = crypto.createHash('sha1')
    .update(KEY)
    .update(METHOD.toLowerCase())
    .update(SERVICE.toLowerCase())
    .update(date)
    .digest('hex');
console.log(encoded);

const baseEncoded = btoa(encoded);
console.log(baseEncoded);
```

However the end codes are not comparable.

Python generates using the given inputs: *b'oV4RJ6pAz+hxZsxeQthx8gZrhAY='*

Javascript generates: *YTZjMmIyYjQzOGEwZGUxZTU1YTNjMWVlYjA3MTA3NTFmODc0MDM3ZQ==*

I googled around but could not find what to change to make this work.
In python the digest is hashlib.sha1, this is not available in crypto.

Any pointers?

Below are the codes Python generates at each of the update steps.

```
-----> key: b'bnAcIlriz+t4hTQLBrnjI1aeXBI='
-----> method: b'rc1Y6wKZo8pDKHmhjVNDkhcVNKM='
-----> Service: b'/urBh6Yqk6QI39JhYtSMI9P9QS8='
-----> Time: 5d016f32-452f-4b9b-8e81-641e14d4d98c
-----> Identifier: b'oV4RJ6pAz+hxZsxeQthx8gZrhAY='
-----> FINAL: b'oV4RJ6pAz+hxZsxeQthx8gZrhAY='
```

Solution:

```
const encoded = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key)
    .update(METHOD.toLowerCase())
    .update(SERVICE.toLowerCase())
    .update(date)
    .update(identify)
    .digest('base64');
```

Comment: This looks like Node crypto. Since you are using and HMAC in python, you should use `crypto.createHmac()` in javascript. And yes, SHA1 is usually available.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I tried the createHmac, this needs an algorithm, which is not an issue it's SHA1 and it needs a secret. This secret is not a argument that I find in the Python library.

Signatue of createHmac: 

```
function createHmac(algorithm: string, key: crypto.BinaryLike | crypto.KeyObject, options?: internal.TransformOptions | undefined): crypto.Hmac
```

That's why I was trying createHash

Comment: The secret is the first argument to `hmac.new` in python.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, thanks for the pointers. With these I have been able to figure it out.
I added the solution above. I did not understand the KEY was in fact the second argument that needed to be added and that it does not to be included in the update for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback from @PresidentJamesK.Polk I was able to figure this out.

```
const encoded = crypto.createHmac('sha1', key)
    .update(METHOD.toLowerCase())
    .update(SERVICE.toLowerCase())
    .update(date)
    .update(identify)
    .digest('base64');
```